# Extra info displayed in uncaught error vs caught Error object

Tags: node.js, error-handling

If I run an erroneous file `node err.js`

```
console.log(hi);
```

it throws the error, which if uncaught shows this: (note the first two lines)

```
C:\test\err.js:2
    console.log(hi);
                ^
ReferenceError: hi is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\test\err.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:426:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:444:10)
```

But if I try-catch the error and display the Error object:

```
try {
    console.log(hi);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    console.error(err.message);
    console.error(err.stack);
}
```

```
[ReferenceError: hi is not defined]
hi is not defined
ReferenceError: hi is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\test\err.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:426:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:444:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:306:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:948:3
```

Where does this part go:

```
C:\test\err.js:2
    console.log(hi);
                ^
```

How can I retrieve this piece of info from the Error object?